# Find the position of the non-zero minimum in a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list which looks like

```
list = {{0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0, 1, 2}}
```

How can I find the position of the non-zero minimum which is non zero (this should be `6`)

I have this method for finding the maximum:

```
Position[list, Max[list], 3][[1, 1]]
```

Comment: Maybe you are looking for this: `FirstPosition[list, Except[{0}, _List], {1}][[1]]`

Comment: should the result be `{6,2}` ?

Comment: Or this: `Position[list, Min[DeleteCases[list, 0, \[Infinity]]], 3][[1, 1]]`

Comment: or `FirstPosition[list,Min[list /. 0 -> Infinity]]`?